# Simple fragmented Slider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

i found alot of sliders and examples, but none of them fits my needs.

Can anybody help me coding a simple slider like the one in the picture with jquery and html?
When you click on the arrows, the next/previous picture will slide in/out.

Thanks in advance,
Marc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok this is what I got, if anybody is interested. maybe someone can also improve it:

```
$(function() {
var container = $('#slides');
var numImages = 3;
var url = '/image/slide';
for (i = 1; i < numImages + 1; i++) {
    container.append('<img src=' + url + +i + '.png class="sliderImage">');
}
var slides = $('#slides > img');

$(slides[0]).addClass("first");
$(slides[1]).addClass("second");
$(slides[2]).addClass("third");

$("#arrowR").click(function() {
    var el1=$( ".first" );
    var el2=$( ".second" );
    var el3=$( ".third" );
    el3.toggleClass("third first");
    el2.toggleClass("second third");
    el1.toggleClass("first second");


});
$("#arrowL").click(function() {
    var el1=$( ".first" );
    var el2=$( ".second" );
    var el3=$( ".third" );

    el1.toggleClass("first third");
    el2.toggleClass("second first");
    el3.toggleClass("third second");
});
}
);
```

The CSS-classes first, second and third define the position of the image. That means it only works for 3 pictures! NOT A GOOD SOLUTION